# Log columns of ArrayList in Android project

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList called "alist" with rows and columns from a database. The column entries have values of integers or reals. I am trying to log each column value in a row, then go to the next row and repeat.

```
for (int i = 0; i<alist.size(); i++){
        Log.d("Value: ", (alist.get(i).toString()));
}
```

When I test the app, the log reads as follows:

```
04-13 17:30:18.639 11608-11608/com.awilliams.package D/Value:: com.awilliams.package.Value@756ef12
04-13 17:30:18.639 11608-11608/com.awilliams.package D/Value:: com.awilliams.package.Value@6c776e3
```

How do I log the actual values?

Comment: What exactly is com.awilliams.package.Value?  It sounds like you need to reach into it and pull out the values of interest.

Comment: Implementing the toString() method in the class com.awilliams.package.Value should help.

Comment: Where did you declared and initialized "alist" ? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1):

in model Value.class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return your_variable;
}
```

Or

```
aList.get(i).getName().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saying there are rows and columns but i do not see 2 nested for-loops?

```
for (rows) {
    for (cols) {
    }
}
```